# Very slow Absolute value computation (Improvement need)?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have to compute the following absolute value. When computing the absolute value of the two pieces separately, everything works fine. When summing up and then evaluating the Abs of the Sum, the code gets very slow. I am still waiting for the result which I am not sure I will get. Do I need to improve the code, giving more assumptions/options?

```
 part = FullSimplify[
 Abs[(1 - (1 - I)*(beta/2)^(1/2)*Exp[-(1 - I)/2*(beta/2)^(1/2)]*
       Cosh[(1 - I) Sqrt[beta/2] z])*(dWNorm[
      x]) + (Z0 I beta dWNorm1/
       2)*((Exp[(1 - I) Sqrt[beta/2] z] - 
        Exp[-(1 - I) Sqrt[beta/2] z])/(Exp[(1 - I)/2 *
           Sqrt[beta/2]]*(1 - I) Sqrt[beta/2] - 2))*(S[x])]^2 // 
ComplexExpand, beta > 0];
```

There are a couple of undefined functions, because the result I want must be independent from them (I will define them later in my code). 
What I find very weird is also that if I remove `FullSimplify`together with the hypothesis that beta>0, I get a very fast result. However, this result includes Arg[beta], which is 0 when beta is real and >0. Why does Mathematica get so slow if I give such an hypothesis? However, if I use `Refine`, together with the above mentioned hypothesis, I get again a very fast result.